# What does restoring an iPad from an iPhone backup actually do?

Tags: iphone, ipad, backup, restore

### Context

Recently, one of my relatives upgraded her [iPad Air 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPad_Air_2) to [iPadOS 15.6.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPadOS_15). She recalls that she purchased the iPad in 2013 and it hadn't been upgraded recently; it may have still been running a version of [iOS 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_8) prior to the upgrade.

The upgrade malfunctioned in some way (she recalls that an error appeared at one point, but not what it said) and the iPad is now behaving as if it's new, i.e., her account has been lost or at least rendered inaccessible. I'm trying to help her recover data she had on the iPad (or at least determine if such recovery is even possible); unfortunately, these data weren't backed up before the upgrade, so they exist only on the iPad (provided the upgrade didn't erase them).

### Question

When her iPad is plugged into her MacBook, a "Welcome to your new iPad" window is displayed with a prompt asking "Would you like to set up this iPad as a new iPad or restore your information from a previous backup?" In the "restore from this backup" dropdown menu, the only option is an iPhone backup from a few years ago.

[image: iPad restore from backup window]

What would restoring the iPad from this iPhone backup actually do? [Apple's documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT204136) (see the "Can I use my device's backup for another kind of device, such as an iPhone backup for an iPad?" section) only describes the type of content that *won't* be transferred.

Would restoring the iPad from this iPhone backup just copy applicable account details in the iPhone backup to the iPad? If so, would that allow my relative to access the data on her iPad (assuming it wasn't erased during the upgrade process)? My guess is "probably not" since according to [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/191348/recovering-data-from-factory-reset-ipad/193214#193214) and [this page from Apple's documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/guide/security/sece3bee0835/web) data on iPads is encrypted using a key linked to the associated user account. Perhaps it might work if the account in the iPhone backup is the same one as and/or linked to the one that was originally on the iPad?

Any details would be much appreciated; I'm hoping this might be worth a shot but don't want to make the situation worse.

Comment: a point of clarification – although I don't think it's relevant to your question, but just in case: the screen you are showing shows the first time you connect a device to a Mac, even when it's already set up. You can click "Set up as a new device" and nothing will be done to the iPad.

Comment: @Ezekiel Ah, so "set up as new device" really means "set up as a device that's new to this MacBook". That's good to know, thanks!

Comment: It's left over from when this was the only way to set up a new device - but now you can set up the device before connecting it so this screen is nonsense